# How do I mount the ./logs folder for (Docker) apache airflow on Windows 10?

Tags: docker, airflow

I am following the instructions here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.1/start/docker.html

I see that airflow will try to create folders in the ./logs, but it doesn't have permission.

If I remove logs from:

```
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
```

it works and the service starts.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problems, and I think it was caused by running

`echo -e "AIRFLOW_UID=$(id -u)\nAIRFLOW_GID=0" > .env`

and the user id set as AIRFLOW_UID somehow doesn't have permission to create folders in ./logs.

You can try
`docker container inspect {container_name}`
or
`docker logs -f {container_name}`  for greater details of errors.